# how to send SMS from a cakephp application and display a message if successful?

Tags: cakephp, sms

I am building an application in cakephp where I need to send an sms to a newly registered user. I can send sms by using redirect function but then it doesn't get automatically revert back to my webpage.

Comment: please briefly elaborate what's your real problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at this plugin:
https://github.com/fotografde/cakephp-sms